# How update/remove an item already cached within a collection of items

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache, spring-3, spring-cache

I am working with Spring and EhCache

I have the following method

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value="products", key="#root.target.PRODUCTS")
public Set<Product> findAll() {
    return new LinkedHashSet<>(this.productRepository.findAll());
}
```

I have other methods working with @Cacheable and @CachePut and @CacheEvict.

Now, imagine the database returns 100 products and they are cached through `key="#root.target.PRODUCTS"`, then other method would **insert - update - deleted** an item into the database. Therefore the products cached through the `key="#root.target.PRODUCTS"` are not the same anymore such as the database.

I mean, check the two following two methods, they are able to update/delete an item, and that **same item** is cached in the other `key="#root.target.PRODUCTS"`

```
@Override
@CachePut(value="products", key="#product.id")
public Product update(Product product) {
    return this.productRepository.save(product);
}

@Override
@CacheEvict(value="products", key="#id")
public void delete(Integer id) {
    this.productRepository.delete(id);
}
```

I want to know if is possible update/delete the item located in the cache through the `key="#root.target.PRODUCTS"`, it would be 100 with the Product updated or 499 if the Product was deleted.

My point is, I want avoid the following:

```
@Override
@CachePut(value="products", key="#product.id")
@CacheEvict(value="products", key="#root.target.PRODUCTS")
public Product update(Product product) {
    return this.productRepository.save(product);
}

@Override
@Caching(evict={
        @CacheEvict(value="products", key="#id"),
        @CacheEvict(value="products", key="#root.target.PRODUCTS")
})
public void delete(Integer id) {
    this.productRepository.delete(id);
}
```

I don't want call again the 500 or 499 products to be cached into the `key="#root.target.PRODUCTS"`

Is possible do this? How?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caching the collection using the caching abstraction is a duplicate of what the underlying caching system is doing. And because this is a duplicate, it turns out that you have to resort to some kind of duplications in your own code in one way or the other (the duplicate key for the set is the obvious representation of that). And because there is duplication, you have to sync state somehow

If you really need to access to the whole set and individual elements, then you should probably use a shortcut for the easiest leg. First, you should make sure your cache contains all elements which is not something that is obvious. Far from it actually. Considering you have that:

```
//EhCacheCache cache = (EhCacheCache) cacheManager.getCache("products");


@Override
public Set<Product> findAll() {
    Ehcache nativeCache = cache.getNativeCache();
    Map<Object, Element> elements = nativeCache.getAll(nativeCache.getKeys());
    Set<Product> result = new HashSet<Product>();
    for (Element element : elements.values()) {
        result.add((Product) element.getObjectValue());
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(result);
}
```

The `elements` result is actually a lazy loaded map so a call to `values()` may throw an exception. You may want to loop over the keys or something.

You have to remember that the caching abstraction eases the access to the underlying caching infrastructure and in no way it replaces it: if you had to use the API directly, this is probably what you would have to do in some sort.

Now, we can keep the conversion on [SPR-12036](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12036) if you believe we can improve the caching abstraction in that area. Thanks!

Comment: Thank You Stephane, I am going keep the conversation through JIRA.

Answer (score 5):

I think something like this schould work... Actually it's only a variation if "Stéphane Nicoll" answer ofcourse, but it may be useful for someone. I write it right here and haven't check it in IDE, but something similar works in my Project.

1. Override CacheResolver:

   ```
   @Cacheable(value="products", key="#root.target.PRODUCTS", cacheResolver = "customCacheResolver")
   ```
2. Implement your own cache resolver, which search "inside" you cached items and do the work in there

   ```
   public class CustomCacheResolver implements CacheResolver{
     private static final String CACHE_NAME = "products";
     @Autowired(required = true) private CacheManager cacheManager;

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   @Override
   public Collection<? extends Cache> resolveCaches(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> cacheOperationInvocationContext) {
     // 1. Take key from query and create new simple key
     SimpleKey newKey;
     if (cacheOperationInvocationContext.getArgs().length != null) { //optional
       newKey = new SimpleKey(args); //It's the key of cached object, which your "@Cachable" search for           
     } else {
       //Schould never be... DEFAULT work with cache if something wrong with arguments
       return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME)));
     }

     // 2. Take cache
     EhCacheCache ehCache = (EhCacheCache)cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME);  //this one we bringing back                
     Ehcache cache = (Ehcache)ehCache.getNativeCache();  //and with this we working        
     // 3. Modify existing Cache if we have it
     if (cache.getKeys().contains(newKey) && YouWantToModifyIt) {
       Element element = cache.get(key);
       if (element != null && !((List<Products>)element.getObjectValue()).isEmpty()) {
       List<Products> productsList = (List<Products>)element.getObjectValue();
       // ---**--- Modify your "productsList" here as you want. You may now Change single element in this list.                   
       ehCache.put(key, anfragenList); //this method NOT adds cache, but OVERWRITE existing                            
     // 4. Maybe "Create" new cache with this key if we don't have it
     } else {
       ehCache.put(newKey, YOUR_ELEMENTS);
     }
     return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(ehCache));  //Bring all back - our "new" or "modified" cache is in there now...
   }
   ```

Read more about CRUD of EhCache: [EhCache code samples](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/code-samples.html#using-caches)

Hope it helps. And sorry for my English:(

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a way to read the collection from underlying cache structure of spring. You can retrieve the collection from underlying **ConcurrentHashMap** as key-value pairs without using **EhCache** or anything else. Then you can update or remove an entry from that collection and then you can update the cache too. Here is an example that may help:

```
import com.crud.model.Post;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperationInvocationContext;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheResolver;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.*;


@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomCacheResolver implements CacheResolver {

private static final String CACHE_NAME = "allPost";

@Autowired
private CacheManager cacheManager;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Collection<? extends Cache> resolveCaches(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> cacheOperationInvocationContext) {

    log.info(Arrays.toString(cacheOperationInvocationContext.getArgs()));

    String method = cacheOperationInvocationContext.getMethod().toString();
    Post post = null;
    Long postId = null;
    if(method.contains("update")) {
        //get the updated post
        Object[] args = cacheOperationInvocationContext.getArgs();
        post = (Post) args[0];
    }
    else if(method.contains("delete")){
        //get the post Id to delete
        Object[] args = cacheOperationInvocationContext.getArgs();
        postId = (Long) args[0];
    }


    //read the cache
    Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME);

    //get the concurrent cache map in key-value pair
    assert cache != null;
    Map<SimpleKey, List<Post>> map = (Map<SimpleKey, List<Post>>) cache.getNativeCache();

    //Convert to set to iterate
    Set<Map.Entry<SimpleKey, List<Post>>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<SimpleKey, List<Post>>> itr = entrySet.iterator();

    //if a iterated entry is a list then it is our desired data list!!! Yayyy
    Map.Entry<SimpleKey, List<Post>> entry = null;
    while (itr.hasNext()){
        entry = itr.next();
        if(entry instanceof List) break;
    }

    //get the list
    assert entry != null;
    List<Post> postList = entry.getValue();

    if(method.contains("update")) {
        //update it
        for (Post temp : postList) {
            assert post != null;
            if (temp.getId().equals(post.getId())) {
                postList.remove(temp);
                break;
            }
        }
        postList.add(post);
    }
    else if(method.contains("delete")){
        //delete it
        for (Post temp : postList) {
            if (temp.getId().equals(postId)) {
                postList.remove(temp);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    //update the cache!! :D
    cache.put(entry.getKey(),postList);

    return new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME)));
}
}
```

Here are the methods that uses the **CustomCacheResolver**

```
@Cacheable(key = "{#pageNo,#pageSize}")
public List<Post> retrieveAllPost(int pageNo,int pageSize){ // return list}

@CachePut(key = "#post.id",cacheResolver = "customCacheResolver")
public Boolean updatePost(Post post, UserDetails userDetails){ //your logic}

@CachePut(key = "#postId",cacheResolver = "customCacheResolver")
public Boolean deletePost(Long postId,UserDetails userDetails){ // your logic}

@CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
public Boolean createPost(String userId, Post post){//your logic}
```

Hope it helps to manipulate your spring application cache manually!

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't see any easy way, but you can override Ehcache cache functionality by supplying [cache decorator](http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/cache-decorators). Most probably you'd want to use [EhcahceDecoratorAdapter](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/EhcacheDecoratorAdapter.html), to enhance functions used by [EhCacheCache](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.context/3.1.0/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheCache.java?av=f) put and evict methods.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and rude solution is :

```
@Cacheable(key = "{#pageNo,#pageSize}")
public List<Post> retrieveAllPost(int pageNo,int pageSize){ // return list}

@CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
public Boolean updatePost(Post post, UserDetails userDetails){ //your logic}

@CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
public Boolean deletePost(Long postId,UserDetails userDetails){ // your logic}

@CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
public Boolean createPost(String userId, Post post){//your logic}
```